# Reportportal client-java-4.0.0.BETA-1 jar is missing

Tags: logback, reportportal

Reportportal's logger-java-logback-4.0.0.BETA-1 is referring to client-java-4.0.0.BETA-1 but this jar has been removed from artifactory. Can the owners please put it back.
https://bintray.com/epam/reportportal/client-java

4.0.0 is not working for me for which I have posted another question.

If I can atl;east get the logback BETA jar, I can get by for sometime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as RELEASE versions are pushed to bintray, public BETAs are being removed to avoid reaching Bintray storage size limits. Please, use 4.0.x